# How can i make a connection between two schemes in monogo db using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, migration

if i have the following two schemas

1. User
2. Role

---

User Schema has

1. username
2. password
3. roletype

---

Role Schema has

1. userType

---

So how can i connect between the two schemas in mongoose so when i create a role and then when i create user and when it comes to the usertype, i am only graping and saving the data that comes from the role schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Schema.Types.ObjectId

```
 var userSchema = new Schema({
        username:String,
        password:String,
        role: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'roleschema' },

});
```

Comment: well, i tried this and when i created an user, it doesn't save the userRole and i check the db, it only shows the username and password. if u wanna see more about this question here :
https://stackoverflow.com/q/69988540/15454800